# No such file or directory Eclipse Java Mac OSX

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, filenotfoundexception

I keep getting this error every time I run my OpenGL program and try and set up a texture:

```
Unable to read texture file: java.io.FileNotFoundException: bricks.gif (No such file or directory)
```

I have the file bricks.gif in the same folder and it shows up in Eclipse as well, but I have no idea what is going on. I tried to clean and refresh as well, but nothing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Two ideas for solving your problem:

1. Make the reference to bricks.gif absolute, adding the full path.
   (e.g. /Users/abc/workspace/bricks.gif)
2. When Eclipse starts your Application, the directory root will be your project folder.

Think of the following layout in Eclipse Package Explorer:

```
projectname
   -src
   -bin
   -...
   -bricks.gif
```

You can refer to the file in relative way by using the path "./bricks.gif". You can obtain a File Object pointing to bricks.gif with the following code:

```
File bricks = new File("./bricks.gif");
```

or

```
File bricks = new File("bricks.gif");
```

Cheers

Comment: I will not be able to use the second method because I have to pass the path in a method that cannot be changed as a string. The first method worked, but is there any way I can make it so others could use the program as well, without having to change the path every time?

Comment: No, it doesn't. I get this: Unable to read texture file: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./bricks.gif (No such file or directory)

Comment: Could you extend your question with some code-snippets, so one can see, which operations are relevant?